# Can a finite subset of a ring generate more than one ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

If $A$ is a finite subset of a ring $R$, then the smallest ideal containing $A$ is denoted $\langle A \rangle$.

I would like to know if there are more than one ideal that $A$ could generate in $R$ (of course except the zero ideal) and if so, then will every ideal generated by $A$ contain $A$ in it?

The ring $R$ is not necessarily commutative.

Any help or hint will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "the smallest" means that it's contained in every ideal containing $A$. That implies it is unique, because two ideals with that property would have to contain one another.

Comment: As you say yourself, $\langle A\rangle$ contains $A$. This answers your second question.

Comment: For any subset $A$ of $R$ then $(A)_L = \sum_{a \in A} aR= \{ b \in R, b = \sum_{a \in A}  ac_a\}$ is the smallest left ideal containing $A$.

Comment: Inclusion of ideals of $R$ is a partial order; ideals are subsets of the underlying set of $R$. The uniqueness is proved in *order theory*, and this proof does not employ ring theory at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only one ideal generated by $A$, note that it says that it is "the smallest ideal containing $A$." It is "the smallest" and there can be only one that is "the smallest."

What needs to be checked though, for this definition to make sense, is that there actually is such a smallest ideal. In principle, there could be for example several ideals that contain $A$ that are minimal with that property but pairwise incomparable. Or there could be none.

To this end one usually shows that the intersection of ideals is an ideal.
Further one notes that the full ring is an ideal, and thus there always is an ideal that contains $A$.

An alternative way to define it would be to say that $\langle A \rangle$ is the intersection of all ideals that contain $A$. The full ring is always in the intersection. In this case uniqueness would be clearer, but one would have to check that the intersection actually is an ideal.